# Android Studio Firebase

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

Здравствуйте у меня следующая проблема. При запуске приложения оно вылетает с ошибкой App has been stoped. По логам ошибка указывает на
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

Перепробовал много вариантов - не помогает.

**Вот лог ошибок**

```
2019-03-26 22:36:48.960 8571-8571/com.example.sms E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sms, PID: 8571
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sms/com.example.sms.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.sms. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.sms. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(SourceFile:218)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source:1)
        **at com.example.sms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)**
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**MainActvity**

```
   package com.example.sms;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button registration;
    private EditText mail;
    private EditText password;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    protected FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        registration = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registration);
        mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mail);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        registration.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void registerUser(){
        String email = mail.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass = password.getText().toString().trim();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please,enter email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please,enter password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;

        }
        progressDialog.setMessage("Registrening...");
        progressDialog.show();

        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Succefully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==registration){
           registerUser();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: в ошибке написано: `Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first`. инициализируйте, прежде чем обращаться

Comment: Инициализировал, все равно не помогло

Comment: Он ругается на вот эту строчку         firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
Перед  ней написана инициализация приложения

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977847/make-sure-to-call-firebaseapp-initializeappcontext-first-in-android